# FCN dimension in ConvNet+FCN example

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, pytorch

So my neural network defined in pytorch is as follows (taken from https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/neural_networks_tutorial.html)

```
class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        # 1 input image channel, 6 output channels, 3x3 square convolution
        # kernel
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 6, 3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 3)
        # an affine operation: y = Wx + b
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 6 * 6, 120)  # 6*6 from image dimension
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Max pooling over a (2, 2) window
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), (2, 2))
        # If the size is a square you can only specify a single number
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), 2)
        x = x.view(-1, self.num_flat_features(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

    def num_flat_features(self, x):
        size = x.size()[1:]  # all dimensions except the batch dimension
        num_features = 1
        for s in size:
            num_features *= s
        return num_features
```

Assuming I want to apply NN on a 1 * 32 * 32 tensor, how does `self.fc1` come to be 16 * 6 * 6. I understand the 16, not sure how we get 6.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your convolutions are 3x3 kernels without padding, meaning the data will loss 1 off each side of it's spatial dimensions when passing through. If you're confused as to why, seeing a picture is best:

[image: no pad conv]

The blue is your input data and the green the resulting data (one channel each).

Let's step through and see what happens:

```
Input->    1x32x32
conv1->    6x30x30 (lost 2 on each spatial dimension)
max_pool-> 6x15x15 (halves the spatial dimensions)
conv2->    16x13x13
max_pool-> 16x6x6 (13 doesn't divide evenly)
```

And there you have it!